# The cFS question was closed and deleted too early

Tags: discussion

This question, [What are the uses of the NASA core Flight System (cFS)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17353/nasa-cfs-core-flight-system-http-prn-to-29shn5w-turns-open-source), while perhaps too broad and perhaps not well written, was in my opinion closed far too early.

Flight software is a huge component of the cost of a new space vehicle.  cFS has the potential to be a huge game changer in how we write flight software. Open source (e.g., Linux, Python, numpy/scipy, NetCDF, OpenCL, OpenGL, OpenVDB, Blender, CMake, VTK, ...) has drastically changed how software (and scientific software) is written and used. cFS is one of the shining lights in NASA's late entry into the open source game.

Just sayin'.

Comment: Keep in mind, you can always ask a question of your own to replace it. Even if it is a question that you can self-answer.

Comment: The question has been reopened now after and edit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm hopeful that can be opened, but there's a few reasons why it was closed:

1. Using URL shorteners in a question is highly discouraged.
2. Using one in a title is even worse.
3. There wasn't really much meat to the question.

I'm keeping an eye on it, and working with the OP to meet the level of quality, but as it stands right now, it isn't there. Quite frankly, it looks like spam in its current form. It has nothing to do with the question that it was closed, and everything to do with the quality.

Comment: Somewhat better now?

Comment: Yeah, good enough for now.